# Postman return empty Json result web api

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I have created the employee.json which will have id,firstname and lastname i am try to get the json reponse back, but postman return me an empty json object

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class EmployeeController : ControllerBase
{

    public JsonResult Get()
    {

        var jsonFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Employee.json");
        List<Employee> employee =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Employee>>(jsonFile);
        return new JsonResult(new Employee(1, "Toyota", "Aygo"));
    }
}
```

here is the employee.json file

```
[{
  "id": 1,  
  "firstname": "First Employee First Name",
  "lastname": "First Employee Last Name"
  },
  {
  "id": 2,  
  "firstname": "Second Employee First Name",
  "lastname": "Second Employee Last Name"
 }]
```

Below is the Postman response

[image]

Comment: Are your `Employee` class properties/fields private?

Answer (score 1):

1. Check the name of your file **Employee.json not employee.json**
   which should be same as codes in controller.

   [image]
2. Set `Employee` Model as below

```
public class Employee
{
    public Employee(int id, string firstname, string lastname)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.FirstName = firstname;
        this.LastName = lastname;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Codes of Controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class EmployeeController : ControllerBase
{

    public JsonResult Get()
    {
        var jsonFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"D:\Users\Employee.json");
        List<Employee> employee = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Employee>>(jsonFile);
        //return new JsonResult(new Employee(1, "Toyota", "Aygo"));

        return new JsonResult(employee);
    }
}
```

Result
[image]